# Getting error in <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('customer')"/> in spring security basic authentication?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, basic-authentication

> This is my rest-dispather-servlet-security.xml file

I have used the XML based configuration in my spring security but I am getting an error in
my access attribute **access="hasAnyRole('customer')"**. Here is my xml file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service id="userService ">
                <security:user name="xxx" password="xxx" authorities="customer" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <security:http create-session="stateless"
        use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('customer')"/>
        <security:http-basic />
    </security:http>

</beans>
```

> also while accessing it through postman I am able to authenticate the URL but getting the following error

```
HTTP Status 403 â€“ Forbidden
Type Status Report
Message Access is denied
Description The server understood the request but refuses to authorise it.
Apache Tomcat/8.5.12
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Springboot Security hasRole not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946473/springboot-security-hasrole-not-working)

Comment: no sir, that is annotation based configuration and I tried that but I failed again. Can you please give some other solution for it.

Comment: That makes no difference, it is the same with XML. It has to be `authorities="ROLE_customer"`(with prefix).

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
<security:user name="xxx" password="xxx" authorities="customer" />
```

to

```
<security:user name="xxx" password="xxx" authorities="ROLE_customer" />
```

and you are done